# has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have a MySQL, Express, Angular, NodeJS application and sometimes when I log in I get the following error in my node console:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

The error occurs in my `passport.local.js` file, this is the line:

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE ?', [username], function (err, user) {
```

This is the passport function

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {

        console.log('app.js');

        pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {

            console.log('err: ' + err);
            console.log(connection);    

            connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE ?', [username], function (err, user) {
                if (err) throw err;

                for (var i = user.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    var current = user[i];
                }

                if(current){
                    if(bcrypt.compareSync(password, current.password)){
                        return done(null, user);
                    } else {
                        return done(null, false);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log('no user');
                    return done(null, false);
                }
            });

            connection.release();
        });
    }
));
```

I require my `pool` in the top of my file

```
var pool = require('../../config/connection');
```

When the error occurs the:

```
console.log(connection);
```

Gets:

> undefined

I also log the error:

```
console.log('err: ' + err);
```

Shows:

```
 err: Error: ER_USER_LIMIT_REACHED: User 'bfe4a8980ede74' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 10)
```

Comment: Maybe you are spawning too many processes. Make sure you close any connection you make after you are done with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error you're getting is stating the issue: your MySQL server is only allowing 10 connection per user, and that limit has been reached.

The [default for the `mysql` connection pool](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pool-options) also happens to be 10, which is cutting it really close. If any other MySQL client besides your Express app is connected to the database with the same user credentials, you may run into that particular error. I would suggest increasing `max_user_connections` in the MySQL configuration.

Aside from that, there's another issue with your code: it's releasing the connection before the query has finished, which may lead to unexpected behaviour. Move the call to `connection.release()` to inside the callback:

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  ...
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE ?', [username], function (err, user) {
    connection.release();
    ...
  });
});
```

If this is a common way you're using MySQL (get a connection, perform a query, release the connection), you can make life a bit easier by using `pool.query()` instead. See [this example](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections).

And finally, if you're working with async code, don't throw errors but pass them to the callback (and make sure that you actually handle them, because you're not handling any errors from `pool.getConnection` now, besides logging them):

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  if (err) return done(err);
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I do have 2 questions though. Is there a negative effect on increasing the max connections and do you think there's an error in my code somewhere that causes the overflood of connections to the db?

Comment: @PeterBoomsma I don't think you're flooding the database with connections, it's just that the maximum allowed number of connection is exactly the same as the number of connections the pool will (lazily) open. If `mysql` happens to open an extra connection (for whatever reason), you'll run into that limit. Increasing is to, say, 20, should probably be enough. And unless you have wildly underpowered hardware, I don't think that there will be a negative impact.

Comment: I have my MySQL database on Heroku. Guess I need to configure the DB on that platform. I just changed the value in my own config but I still get the error.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma alternatively, you could try and lower the `connectionLimit` value of the connection pool.

Comment: For Heroku: try restarting your dyno(s).

Answer (score 8):

I am assuming that your `max_user_connections` is set to 10. Please increase the `max_user_connection` value.

```
show global variables like '%connections%';
```

Will help you in giving the no of connections you have set. Increase the number of connections If its less than 25 or 50. Max connections can be more than 16000 I guess, it all depends on your cpu, no of threads It can handle etc.

```
SET GLOBAL max_user_connections=100;
```

`max_user_connections` is a dynamic variable, which means you can directly run this query. You donot have to shutdown mysql.

Comment: `SET GLOBAL max_user_connections=100;` gives `Error Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation` this error. I am using clearDB-mySql from heroku. What should I do?