# Too many mysql connections / optimizing mysql query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, azure

After using my node applications for a couple of time I always get problems with too many MySQL queries. Currently I am using a MySQL Connection Pool which already increased the stability but isn't a final solution.

Is there a better way to connect to the MySQL database and close the connection directly after the query?

General "MySQL Connection":

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');
const config = require('config');
const dbConfig = config.get('Azure.dbConfig');

console.log(`used mysql information: ${dbConfig}`);
const con = mysql.createPool(dbConfig
);

con.on('enqueue', () => {
    console.log('connection enqued')
});
con.on('connection', function (connection) {
    connection.query('SET SESSION auto_increment_increment=1')
});

con.on('release', function (connection) {
    console.log('Connection %d released', connection.threadId);
});

module.exports = con;
```

Example for a MySQL query:

```js
const con = require('../db.js');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');



module.exports = function (app) {
    
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }));

    app.get('/dbCompareName', function (req, res) {

        const ingredients = [];

        con.query('SELECT wm_wine.name, wm_wine.avocandoIngredient, wm_wine.jahrgang, wm_wine.sorte, wm_cart.anzahl, wm_wine.typ from wm_wine INNER JOIN wm_cart on wm_cart.id = wm_wine.id', function (err, result, info) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('while querying the mysql database, an error occurred');
                console.log(err);
                if (err.fatal === true) {
                    con.connect(err => {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        logger.info('reconnected to mysql database');
                    });               
                };
            }
            else {
                const transfer = result;
                
            };

};
```

Comment: Read the node.js manual https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#terminating-connections

Comment: I am using the "Connection Pooling" as stated in the manual. 
I do not want to close the connection to my MySQL database completely because quite a lot of queries happen within seconds - creating a new connection each time would waste a lot of time. Am I right?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly obtaining the connection using 'pool.getConnection' and then explicitly releasing the connection to the pool using 'pool.release'?
What errors exactly when you say 'problems with too many MySQL queries'?

Comment: { Error: ER_USER_LIMIT_REACHED: User 'XXX' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 10)

Comment: This should help -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39150633/has-exceeded-the-max-user-connections-resource